# Do we have to delete AWS EC2 fleets of type 'instant' whose instances have been terminated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to launch many fleets of type "instant", and was wondering if I need (and if so, how?) to delete the fleet request of type "instant" after I got the instances.

I could delete the fleet straight away after I get the response, but I want to keep the instances running after I delete the fleet request because I handle the lifecycle myself, but it doesn't seem to be possible [according to the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteFleets.html#:%7E:text=For%20instant%20fleets%2C%20EC2%20Fleet%20must%20terminate%20the%20instances%20when%20the%20fleet%20is%20deleted.%20A%20deleted%20instant%20fleet%20with%20running%20instances%20is%20not%20supported.).

If it was fine not to delete the fleet request (provided I can be sure there are no additional costs even if I never delete my requests) that would be great, but I couldn't find anything stating that in the docs or the dev guide.

The only thing I know for sure is that there is [no quota](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/fleet-quotas.html#:%7E:text=%E2%81%B4%20This%20quota%20only%20applies%20to%20fleets%20of%20type%20request%20or%20maintain.%20This%20quota%20does%20not%20apply%20to%20instant%20fleets.) on the number of fleets of type instant. It also looks like [it used to be not possible](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/11/amazon-ec2-fleet-now-supports-deleting-instant-type-fleets/) to delete fleet requests of type instant.

I want to avoid if possible wait until I terminated the instances before deleting the fleet request because that would add some complexity to what I need to do.

It also looks not too handy to find my instant fleet requests with [describe-fleets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-fleets.html#:%7E:text=the%20EC2%20Fleets.-,Note,the%20fleet%20ID%2C%20otherwise%20it%20does%20not%20appear%20in%20the%20response.,-(string)).

I would appreciate any help here.
Thanks !